# Sparql variable getting out all bounded

Tags: sparql

I have a triple store whith chemicals. Each substance has has around 30-40 *Parameters*. Each Parameter has a *Database Name* and a real name. For Example *chem:flBeiRT* has the real name *Flüssig bei Raumtemperatur* (german). To break the list up to a more readable size we have created Categories. One of those Categories would be : *Nomenklatur* (german).

I have now a Sparql query where a get all the Parameters under *Nomenklatur*

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ?name         
   WHERE{
   ?s iol:name "Nomenklatur" .
   ?x rdf:type iol:property .
   ?x iol:name ?name .
   ?x iol:propertyof ?s .
   }
```

It gives me the real names of all parameters under Nomenklatur as expected. 
In my understanding in the ?x variable are all paramerters already bound with there *Database Name* so i whant to use this direktly for getting all these parameters from one chemical. So i tried to add this direktly to this query. Insted of getting each parameter individually. Since the substance has no id i use a second Query insinde mine to only get that one chemical:

```
SELECT ?name
WHERE{
?s iol:name "Nomenklatur" .
?x rdf:type iol:property .
?x iol:name ?name .
?x iol:propertyof ?s .
{
 SELECT ?o
 WHERE{
   ?x chem:ilAbk "[A_4mim]Al" .
 }
}
}
```

And it still gives me the same eleven Parameters i asked for. But how would i now get all the fitting literas of that chemical ? I tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?o
WHERE{
  ?s iol:name "Nomenklatur" .
  ?x rdf:type iol:property .
  ?x iol:name ?name .
  ?x iol:propertyof ?s .
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?o
    WHERE{
      ?x chem:ilAbk "[C_2mim]Cl" .
      ?x ?p ?o
    }
  }
}
```

But here i get over 312 results what seams to me like each parameter with each literal plus all the uri ? Could somebody please tell me how to acive that ? And Thank you for your time. 
Or do i have to get every parameter alone ? Maybe it helps to see the data or a pice of it :

[screen from Turtle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4oWz.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your sub-SELECT returns a variable `?o`, but this isn't used in the outer SELECT query. SPARQL evaluates the inner sub-SELECT queries first, not the other way around. So the values of your given substance `[C_2mim]Cl` are computed first, then you have to restrict those in the outer SELECT.

I didn't understand your schema, i.e. it's not totally clear to me. Your predicates denote parameters of chemical substances, right? If yes, you would have to restrict the `?p`s to those that do belong to the category.

Comment: Thank you for your time. So the inner sub-SELECT gets evaluated first - did not know that. So i gues it would be better to select first the chemical and then get all the names and the literals and than filter out the what is under _Nomenklatur_.       Yes in the schema each substance has the parameters, these have there own Prefix (chem) and each chem has category.

Comment: Correct. You can use your sub-select, but you need to propagate everything that is necessary to filter on what you want -  in your case probably `?p` **and** `?o`.